# Placement of the unsigned keyword

Tags: c++

Is

```
unsigned int a;
```

the same as

```
int unsigned a;
```

?

I.e., what I want to know, in the following code:

```
typedef int unsigned my_uint32;
```

does the 'unsigned' "refer" to my_uint32 or to int? So is it the same as

```
typedef unsigned int my_uint32;
```

?

Comment: Please review the types in `stdint.h`, as there may already be definitions you can use instead of creating your own.

Comment: I know, I just tried to formulate the question as easy as possible. Thank you for mentioning though, for people who are not aware of cstdint, it is an immensely useful header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot create your own types that are marked `unsigned`/`signed`, so it could *only* apply to the pre-existing type.

Second, yes it is valid to swap the position of that qualifier:

> `[C++11: 7.1.6.2/3]:` When multiple *simple-type-specifiers* are allowed, they can be freely intermixed with other *decl-specifiers* in any order. *[..]*

**So, the two declarations are equivalent.**

Comment: The wording here is awkward; your types can include `signed` and `unsigned` in their definitions. I think you mean that type names defined with `typedef` cannot subsequently be modified with `signed` or `unsigned`. E.g., you cannot do `typedef int foo; unsigned foo x;`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: No, that's not what I meant (though it is of course also the case). `unsigned`/`signed` are not really "modifiers", but form tokens in the names of distinct types. By contrast, types that we define ourselves may have names consisting of only a single token. Unless you can show me that `[our] types can include signed and unsigned in their definitions`...?

Comment: The wording here is awkward: The English words used may be interpreted in more than one way, and the intended meaning may not be clear to people who are not already familiar with the rules of C++. The statement “you cannot create your own types that are marked `unsigned`/`signed`” may, in English, mean that you are not permitted to do `typedef unsigned int foo;` to create an alias `foo` for `unsigned int` because, as we can plainly see, the type `foo` is marked `unsigned`.

Comment: @Eric: Not really, but okay.

Comment: I think what @LightnessRacesinOrbit means, and what was also my thought, is that in my question, it makes no sense for the (un)signed to "belong" to the "my_uint32" word, because it just doesn't make any sense to say (in English) "typedef me a unsigned my_uint32 to be a int", because the compiler wouldn't know what a unsigned my_uint32 would be.

Comment: accepted your answer, mostly because of the reference to the c++ standard

Comment: @Ela782: Groovy, glad you enjoyed it :)

Answer (score 3):

To resume, the syntax is :

```
typedef keywords alias;
```

so `typedef unsigned int my_uint32` is the same as `typedef int unsigned my_uint32;`.

You may be carefull when you define your own type. In your case, you wanna have a 4 bytes type, you should use types defined in stdint.h (uint32_t) if you code in C, or in cstdint if you code in C++, because 'int' is "at least 4 bytes" and not in each case "4 bytes".

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of using cstdint, the example in my question was just an easy example to formulate my question as easy as possible :-)

Comment: This is wrong: that is _not_ the syntax. In particular, the pre-existing type does not have to be keywords at all.

Comment: The grammar for these is, in part, “simple-declaration: decl-specifier-seq[opt] init-declarator-list[opt];”, “decl-specifier-seq: decl-specifier-seq[opt] decl-specifier”, “decl-specifier: storage-class-specifier | type-specifier | function-specifier | **friend** | **typedef**”, “init-declarator: declarator initializer[opt]”, “declarator: direct-declarator | ptr-operator declarator”, “direct-declarator: declarator-id | …”.

Comment: Incorrect. `int` is guaranteed to be at least 2 bytes, not 4 bytes (think for the older 16 bit architectures for example).

Comment: The exact size is implementation defined and should be `sizeof`d. `int` is also not always supposed to be the processor natural type (word).

Answer (score 1):

A C++ declaration (in the simplest case) consists of two parts:
a declaration specifier, and a declarator.  Everything up to
either what is being declared or the first "operator" (e.g. `*`
or `&`) is part of the declaration specifier, where order
doesn't matter.  So you're free to write things like:

```
int const unsigned static i;
```

(if you don't care what your co-worker think of your code).

C has deprecated putting the storage class specifier (`static`,
`extern`, etc.) anywhere but in the first position, and this was
a generally accepted convention since the earliest days of C.
For the rest:

- I've always seen the modifier precede the basic type (e.g.
  `unsigned int`), *when* the basic type appears.  Most of the
  places I've worked will use simply `unsigned`, rather than
  `unsigned int`.
- I've also always seen the `signed`/`unsigned` precede any
  length modifiers: `unsigned long`, rather than `long unsigned`.
- The position of `const` or `volatile` tends to vary.  Most of
  the more experienced programmers I know put it at the very end
  of the declaration specifier, but this is a somewhat recent
  development, and a lot of people continue to use the older
  convention, and put it immediately after the storage class
  specifier.

For all but the storage class specifiers, this is fairly
arbitrary; about the only other rule I'd say is universal is to
not split up the actual type information, as I did in my
example.

Answer (score 0):

The declarations are equivalent.